# How to set Debian Linux default outgoing mail/sendmail application/script?

Tags: php, linux, email, sendmail, telnet

I'm unfamiliar with Linux, but I'm trying to send mail from PHP. Via SSH, I've found my server's `sendmail` and `mail` functions to be incapable of sending mail through SMTP. But, I've had success with `nc` (Netcat) and `telnet`. Is there a way to switch a server's default mail sending application? E.g. from `sendmail` or `mail` to `nc` or `telnet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in your php.ini file under sendmail_path?  (Probably at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)

eg:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

You need this to point into the correct location for your sendmail for mail() to work

Comment: Sorry, just saw Carlos commented on that.

Comment: hey, no problem, we're here to help, didn't we?

Comment: `sendmail_path` is not to set the path for the sendmail binary, but to set the path to your mailing program, be it sendmail, qmail, postfix or your custom command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a PHP library for sending mail, like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), and send mail via SMTP and not via the `mail()` function?

Also, using those libraries you will be able to send more powerful mails (html, attachments) a lot more easily.

And also, and this is what you were looking for (I think), you may take a look to [sendmail_path](http://es.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) configuration option of php to specify your mail sending application command line (seems you can put some parameters to your command).

edit: added info about sendmail_path

Comment: But using the `mail()` function? Why not use a proper mail server or even gmail?